# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I just started learning Backbone JS. In below code, iam just trying to call url **todos/1** expecting to get json data. Instead iam getting error in console as "**Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS**" I didnt understood why index.jsp keep redirecting many times itself.

**Could anyone please explain me what went wrong and also solution too**

**test.jsp**

```
<html>

<head>

<script
    src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script
    src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.2/backbone-min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var myname;
    var myjson;

    //WAY ONE
    $.getJSON("todos/1", alertUser);

    function alertUser(data) {
        console.log(data.id);
        id = data.id;
         alert(id);

        var TodoItem = Backbone.Model.extend({});
        var todoItem = new TodoItem(data);

        var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
            render: function(){
                var html = '<h3>' + this.model.get('description') + '</h3>';
                $(this.el).html(html);
        }});
        var todoView = new TodoView({model : todoItem});
        todoView.render();
        console.log(todoView.el);

    }


</script>

</head>


<body>

</body>


</html>
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
   <%@page import="org.json.JSONObject" %> 


<%

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

obj.put("description", "pick up milk");
obj.put("status", "incomplete");
obj.put("id", 1);

response.setContentType("application/json");

out.print(obj);
%>
```

**MyServlet.java**

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public MyServlet() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    }


}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>MyServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/todos/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Does anyone know please?

Comment: seems no one knows! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my above problem. Hope it might somebody helps.

In **MyServlet.Java** I need to change **below**

```
response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
```

**to**

```
response.sendRedirect("/MyProj/index.jsp");
```